# Convert pixel coordinates to frame coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am using a small window to detect Mario which is represented by a red block. However, this red block is composed of 16 by 12 pixels. I want to take the pixel coordinates I found, and convert this to a normal x/y coordinate system based on the window shown in the image: [Actual frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pPur.png) which should be 13 by 16 grid (NOT pixels).

So for example, if Mario box is in the upper left corner of screen, the coordinates should be 0,0.

I'm also not sure how to actually make the grid.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


class MarioPixels:

def __init__(self):
    self.mario = np.array([

        [[248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0],
         [248, 56, 0]
         ]]
    )

    self.height = len(self.mario)  # specify number of pixels for columns in the frame
    self.width = len(self.mario[0])  # specificy number of pixels representing a line in the frame

    print(self.mario.shape)

# find difference in R, G and B values between what's in window and what's on the frame
def pixelDiff(self, p1, p2):
    return abs(p1[0] - p2[0]), abs(p1[1] - p2[1]), abs(p1[2] - p2[2])

def isMario(self, window, pattern):
    total = [0, 0, 0]
    count = 0
    for line in range(len(pattern)):

        lineItem = pattern[line]
        sample = window[line]

        for pixelIdx in range(len(lineItem)):
            count += 1
            pixel1 = lineItem[pixelIdx]
            pixel2 = sample[pixelIdx]
            d1, d2, d3 = self.pixelDiff(pixel1, pixel2)
            # print(pixelIdx)
            total[0] = total[0] + d1  # sum of difference between all R values found between window and frame
            total[1] = total[1] + d2  # sum of difference between all G values found between window and frame
            total[2] = total[2] + d3  # sum of difference between all B values found between window and frame
            # Mario has a red hat
            # if line == 0 and pixelIdx == 4 and pixel2[0] != 248:
            #    return 1.0

    rscore = total[0] / (
                count * 255)  # divided by count of all possible places the R difference could be calculated
    gscore = total[1] / (
                count * 255)  # divided by count of all possible places the G difference could be calculated
    bscore = total[2] / (
                count * 255)  # divided by count of all possible places the B difference could be calculated

    return (
                       rscore + gscore + bscore) / 3.0  # averaged to find a value between 0 and 1. Num close to 0 means object(mario, pipe, etc.) is there,
    # whereas, number close to 1 means object was not found.

def searchForMario(self, step, state, pattern):

    height = self.height
    width = self.width

    x1 = 0
    y1 = 0
    x2 = width
    y2 = height

    imageIdx = 0
    bestScore = 1.1
    bestImage = None
    bestx1, bestx2, besty1, besty2 = 0, 0, 0, 0

    for y1 in range(0, 240 - height, 8):  # steps in range row, jump by 8 rows
        y2 = y1 + height

        for x1 in range(0, 256 - width, 3):  # jump by 3 columns
            x2 = x1 + width

            window = state[y1:y2, x1:x2, :]
            score = self.isMario(window, pattern)
            # print(imageIdx, score)
            if score < bestScore:
                bestScore = score
                bestImageIdx = imageIdx
                bestImage = Image.fromarray(window)
                bestx1, bestx2, besty1, besty2 = x1, x2, y1, y2

            imageIdx += 1

    bestImage.save('testrgb' + str(step) + '_' + str(bestImageIdx) + '_' + str(bestScore) + '.png')

    return bestx1, bestx2, besty1, besty2
```

Answer (score 0):

It **looks** like you've got a pixel aspect ratio at play here, so the width and height of each "block" in pixels will be different.

Going by your code, your pixel space is 256x240 pixels, but you say that it actually represents a 13x16 grid. This means that every block in the x-domain is (256/13) or about 20 pixels, and in the y-domain (240/16) 15 pixels. This means that "Mario", at 16x12 pixels occupies less than one complete block. Looking at your image, this seems to be a possibility - bushes and clouds also occupy less than one block.

I suggest you first make sure the 13x16 grid is correct (simply because it doesn't seem to match your pixel size exactly, and because the stride sizes in your ranges imply that blocks might actually be 3x8 pixels). Then, you can try to add the grid on to the pixel image simply by setting the value of every pixel that has an x-co-ordinate exactly divisible by 20 equal to (0,0,0) for a black RGB pixel (and also a y-coordinate exactly divisible by 15 - use modulus operator %). To get the "block" co-ordinates, simply divide the x-co by 20 and the y-co by 15 and round down to the nearest whole number (or use // to do the rounding as part of the division).

I've assumed that your pixel co-ordinates also run from top left (0,0) to bottom right (256, 240).